# Named methods and mouse event handlers

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I've been going around in circles with this. Now I know there's something I didn't understand about it, because I made it respond for a while, it never really worked properly.

These conditionals are inside a loop that updates an animation. I only want to listen to mouse motion events when an option equals a value, in other case, I remove the event listener.

The method for handling the mouse motion event is updateMouse and it's called properly according to the state of the variable opt.

```
if (opt == 7) {
    canvas2.addEventListener("onmousemove", updateMouse(canvas2), false);
} else {
    canvas2.removeEventListener("onmousemove", updateMouse, false);
}
```

The problem I get when running the script is: 'Cannot read property clientX of undefined'.

```
function updateMouse(c) {
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    var rect = c.getBoundingClientRect();
    m_pos = {
        x: event.clientX - rect.left,
        y: event.clientY - rect.top
    };
    console.log("salida: " + m_pos.x + " " + m_pos.y);
}
```

Isn't that the correct way to handle mouse events with named methods?

Comment: You're invoking `updateMouse`, not assigning the handler. And your `updateMouse` defines a `c` parameter, but tries to use `e` as though it will have been given the `event` object. You should have the parameter anticipate the `event` object and reference the `canvas2` using `this`. And get rid of `if (!e) var e = window.event;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it should be "mousemove" not "onmousemove"

Second, the mousemove event takes the event as an argument, so to achieve what you want, you can use:

```
function updateMouse(c) {
    return function(e) {
        var e = e | window.event;  //some cases the event doesn't get passed to the function
        var rect = c.getBoundingClientRect();
        m_pos = {
            x: event.clientX - rect.left,
            y: event.clientY - rect.top
        };
        console.log("salida: " + m_pos.x + " " + m_pos.y);
    };
}
```

Long story short, it returns a function that has the correct argument (accepting an event), but still has access to the canvas object you passed in.

Also, you will need to keep track of the result of the call to `updateMouse(canvas2)` and remove that from the canvas, not `updateMouse`

Answer (score 0):

Yep, thanks a lot. I call the method like this:

```
if (opc == 7) {
    canvas2.addEventListener("mousemove", actualizaMouse, false);
} else {
    canvas2.removeEventListener("mousemove", actualizaMouse, false);
}
```

And reference canvas2 in the method like 'this'. The event

```
function actualizaMouse() {
    var e = e | window.event;
    var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    m_pos = {
        x: event.clientX - rect.left,
        y: event.clientY - rect.top
    };
    console.log("salida: " + m_pos.x + " " + m_pos.y);
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help.